# Как вывести результат который получен от API

Tags: python

Есть результат, как вивести отдельные данные, например: print(f"Название Hawaiian hibiscus")

````
{'language': 'en',
 'preferedReferential': 'the-plant-list',
 'query': {'images': ['284e73fb7521165a3a8667d86b377c90',
                      'dc5f659df9a4bcf90fc109830564d821'],
           'includeRelatedImages': False,
           'organs': ['flower', 'leaf'],
           'project': 'all'},
 'remainingIdentificationRequests': 491,
 'results': [{'gbif': {'id': '3152559'},
              'score': 0.98959,
              'species': {'commonNames': ['Hawaiian hibiscus',
                                          'Hibiscus',
                                          'Chinese hibiscus'],
                          'family': {'scientificName': 'Malvaceae',
                                     'scientificNameAuthorship': '',
                                     'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Malvaceae'},
                          'genus': {'scientificName': 'Hibiscus',
                                    'scientificNameAuthorship': '',
                                    'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Hibiscus'},
                          'scientificName': 'Hibiscus rosa-sinensis L.',
                          'scientificNameAuthorship': 'L.',
                          'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Hibiscus '
                                                         'rosa-sinensis'}},
             {'gbif': {'id': '9064581'},
              'score': 0.01084,
              'species': {'commonNames': ['Campanilla',
                                          'Chinese lantern',
                                          'Japanese hibiscus'],
                          'family': {'scientificName': 'Malvaceae',
                                     'scientificNameAuthorship': '',
                                     'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Malvaceae'},
                          'genus': {'scientificName': 'Hibiscus',
                                    'scientificNameAuthorship': '',
                                    'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Hibiscus'},
                          'scientificName': 'Hibiscus schizopetalus (Dyer) '
                                            'Hook.f.',
                          'scientificNameAuthorship': '(Dyer) Hook.f.',
                          'scientificNameWithoutAuthor': 'Hibiscus '
                                                         'schizopetalus'}}],
 'version': '2021-12-14 (5.0)'} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут у вас словарь, внутри которого другие словари и списки. Из словаря брать данные по ключу. Списки - итерировать. Список самих названий - объединять через `join`:

```
for result in json_['results']:
    print(','.join(result['species']['commonNames']))
```